# Field 'id' expected a number but got '' error on creating table entry

Tags: python, django

I'm working on an ebay style auction website. I've created my models and have a form that creates a new listing. When the POST request goes out, the listing gets created when I try to add the listing to the bid, I get the error

Field 'id' expected a number but got ''

I'm fairly new to Django so if you need anything that I haven't included, please let me know!

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = models.URLField()
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='author')
    category_id = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='category', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}: {self.title}'

class Bid(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    bid_count = models.IntegerField()
    listing = models.ForeignKey('Listing', on_delete=models.CASCADE, name='listing', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.slug} ({self.price})'
```

**views.py**

```
def newListing(request):
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            newListingForm = NewListingForm(request.POST)
            if newListingForm.is_valid():
                title = newListingForm.cleaned_data['title']
                description = newListingForm.cleaned_data['description']
                url = newListingForm.cleaned_data['url']
                bid = newListingForm.cleaned_data['bid']
                category_name = newListingForm.cleaned_data['category']
                category = Category.objects.get(title=category_name)
                category_id = category.id
                current_user = request.user
                l = Listing(title=title, description=description, url=url, author=current_user, category_id=category_id)
                l.save()
                print(l.id)
                b = Bid(price=bid, bid_count=0)
                b.listing.add(l.id)
                b.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            newListingForm = NewListingForm()
            return render(request, "auctions/newListing.html", {
                'form': newListingForm
            })
    except Exception as exc:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, exc_obj, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        newListingForm = NewListingForm()
        return render(request, 'auctions/newListing.html', {
            'form': newListingForm
        })
```

**forms.py**

```
class NewListingForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    url = forms.URLField()
    bid = forms.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    category = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())
```

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: You could change your prints to help spot empty strings. `print(l.id)` to `print('id', repr(l.id))`.

Answer (score 1):

As you defined your field as a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), the list is actually a queryset, not a list of strings. From the documentation:

> A QuerySet of model objects from which the choices for the field are derived and which is used to validate the user’s selection. It’s evaluated when the form is rendered.

What is displayed is a label representing the object, and you could have changed it in your form class by adding a `label_from_instance(self, obj)` method.

Thus, this line `category_name = newListingForm.cleaned_data['category']` will return the object `category`, actually not its name.
Instead of these 2 lines :

```py
category_name = newListingForm.cleaned_data['category']
category = Category.objects.get(title=category_name)
```

just put:

```py
category = newListingForm.cleaned_data['category']
```